# Optional chaining and binding

Tags: swift

Inside the optional binding when I assign the variable ammo (and ammo2) I am pretty sure that I should be using `!` to unbox the optional, but on my first attempt I put `?` by mistake and was a little confused why it still worked, can anyone cast some light onto whats going on there?

```
let soldierA = Soldier(name: "Brian")
soldierA.weapon = Weapon()
soldierA.weapon!.grenadeLauncher = GrenadeLauncher()

let soldierB = Soldier(name: "Gavin")
soldierB.weapon = Weapon()

let soldierC = Soldier(name: "Berty")
soldierC.weapon = Weapon()
soldierC.weapon!.grenadeLauncher = GrenadeLauncher()
soldierC.weapon!.grenadeLauncher!.ammo = 234

let missionTeam = [soldierA, soldierB, soldierC]
for eachSoldier in missionTeam {
    if let launcherAvailable = eachSoldier.weapon?.grenadeLauncher? {
        var ammo =  eachSoldier.weapon!.grenadeLauncher!.ammo // PRETTY SURE THIS IS RIGHT
        var ammo2 = eachSoldier.weapon?.grenadeLauncher?.ammo // SHOULD THIS WORK, IT DOES?
        println("SOLDIER: \(eachSoldier.name), Weapon has launcher AMMO: \(ammo)")
    } else {
        println("SOLDIER: \(eachSoldier.name), Weapon does not have launcher ")
    }
}
```

.

```
// CLASSES
class Soldier {
    var name: String
    var weapon: Weapon?
    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }
}

class Weapon {
    var ammo = 500
    var grenadeLauncher: GrenadeLauncher?
}

class GrenadeLauncher {
    var ammo = 20
}
```

## EDIT

Thank you, I was getting confused about how this works, but I now see what is happening. Here is the modified eachSoldier section again, using optional binding with optional chaining...

```
for eachSoldier in missionTeam {
    if let weapon = eachSoldier.weapon? {
        if let launcher = eachSoldier.weapon?.grenadeLauncher? {
            println("SOLDIER: \(eachSoldier.name) Weapon has launcher with \(launcher.ammo) ammo")
        } else {
            println("SOLDIER: \(eachSoldier.name) Weapon does not have launcher ")
        }
    } else {
        println("SOLDIER: \(eachSoldier.name) does not have weapon ")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
soldierC.weapon = Weapon()
soldierC.weapon!.grenadeLauncher = GrenadeLauncher()
soldierC.weapon!.grenadeLauncher!.ammo = 234
```

it is correct in the current pattern.

---

```
var ammo =  eachSoldier.weapon!.grenadeLauncher!.ammo
```

implicitly unwraps the `weapon` and its `grenadeLauncher`; *it does not care of whether or not they  have been inited before*, therefore it could lead a direct crash if your code tries to unwrap when any of them is still a `nil` value.

---

```
var ammo2 = eachSoldier.weapon?.grenadeLauncher?.ammo
```

tries to access the `weapon` and its `grenadeLauncher`; *if the object does not exist, they will be left alone*, therefore nothing happens but the `ammo2` will be `nil` only, and application can proceed.

therefore your flow could be similar to that:

```
for eachSoldier in missionTeam {
    var ammo2 = eachSoldier.weapon?.grenadeLauncher?.ammo
    if ammo2 != nil {
        println("SOLDIER: \(eachSoldier.name), Weapon has launcher AMMO: \(ammo2)")
    } else {
        println("SOLDIER: \(eachSoldier.name), Weapon does not have launcher ")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what [@holex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24245399/1378388) has stated, I would like to say that your case called [Optional Chaining](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/OptionalChaining.html), in which if you use `?` instead of `!` on an optional variable (or constant), that means you are *checking* if the variable (or the constant) is not nil. In other words, it has a value.

The lovely thing about optional chaining is that you can apply it to many levels.
For example:

Let's say you have these two classes:

```
class Student{
    var subjects: [Subject]?
}
class Subject{
    var name: String?
}
```

and you created a variable:

```
var william = Student()
```

At any time, you can print the name of the first subject as this:

```
print(william.subjects?[0].name)
```

*Notice* that the result of that print statement is **nil**, while if you unwrapped it like this:

```
print(william.subjects![0].name)
```

You would get a **run time error**